# HAVING not showing all the results

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to make a program that will read from my database all columns and if these columns have the same age appear more than once ( for example if two rows have the same age 15 these two rows should be shown etc)

This is the code i tried to make:

```
include('dbcon_3.php');  

if ( $mysqli->connect_errno ) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 GROUP BY Age HAVING ( COUNT( Age ) > 1 )";
$result = $mysqli->query( $sql );
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
  while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
     for ( $j = 0; $j <= count( $row ) - 1; $j++ ) {
        echo  $row[$j];
     }
  }
} else if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
   echo "Not found";
}
```

The result from this code is just one of the rows that should be appeared ( i have tested it for three rows, one had the Age of 16 and two the Age of 15. From the last two only the one appeared on screen).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove group by and try

Comment: First there is some sql-error in your query... you can not use * in ( Select * ... Group By ) with Group by clause... i.e You need to specify particular columns in Select Statement when using Group By Clause ...   example  ( Select A,B,C From TableName Group By A,B,C )

Comment: @Fayeq Unfortunately, some DB engines permit this (I think MySQL does) while others (notably Oracle) don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` collapses your hits. You can solve the problem like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Age IN 
(SELECT Age from table2 GROUP BY Age HAVING (COUNT(Age) > 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with a sub query

```
SELECT table2.* FROM table2 
JOIN
(SELECT age FROM table2 GROUP BY Age HAVING (COUNT(Age) > 1)) AS temp 
ON temp.age=table2.age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Surname  
FROM table2 
GROUP BY Name 
group by Age 
HAVING (COUNT(Age) > 1)
```